# Http tag Cache-Control contains public for WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, security

I am required to fix a vulnerability in my web application wherein the Http tag *Cache-Control* contains value *public* for *WebResource.axd*. I do not know what exactly needs to be done to fix it; probably I need to make the value *private*, but **how**?

[image]